# python requests How to send data to a website

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to send a data to this site using the library of requests, and this to make a vote.
You've done the following:
Is this true?

```
import time
import requests
from time import sleep

url = 'http://www.xtremetop100.com/in-post.php?site=1132347673' 
 s = requests.Session()
proxy = "8.8.8.8:8080"
s.headers.update({
'Host': 'www.xtremetop100.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Referer': 'http://www.xtremetop100.com/in.php?site=1132347673',
'DNT': '1',
'Connection': 'close',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Length': '440',
})

proxy = {'http': 'http://' + proxy, 'https': 'https://' + proxy}
data = {
    'site' :"1132347673",
    'secure_captcha_check':"6110",
    'g-recaptcha-response':captcha_response,
    'ticki' :"Vote+for+ZeroConquer[New+Server]"
       }

Cookies =  { 'flowridaoookie':"1",'_gid':"GA1.2.1228802977.1547667122",'_gat_gtag_UA_116540956_1':"1",'_ga':"GA1.2.1330506724.1547667122",'__cfduid':cfduid,'__atuvs':"5c42ed6d02994f98001",'__atuvc':"156|3"}
response = s.post(url,data=data,Cookies=Cookies,proxies=proxy)
time.sleep(5)
```

print response.status_code

I want to verify whether the sender link is correct?
And the pattern of cookies is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi first of all: you just can't because it use captcha.
But i modified your code to get something working if you want to learn more about python because your code has some error and it wil be nice for you to look at mine to see where are your error etc

```
import requests
from time import sleep
import random
url = 'http://www.xtremetop100.com/in-post.php?site=1132347673' 
#This is a list of proxy found on the internet
proxy = ["103.80.236.107:53281",
"185.32.47.250:8080",
"119.101.117.85:9999",
"41.84.135.114:53281",
"1.10.186.105:40161",
"143.255.52.102:40687",
"187.110.93.120:20183",
"60.6.241.72:808",
"176.197.145.246:32649",
"168.90.144.121:8080",
"159.192.202.122:8080",
"81.174.11.227:33803",
"185.34.17.248:58137",
"119.101.117.87:9999",
"182.160.127.53:39984",
"103.19.110.177:8080",
"91.219.235.12:8080",
"36.66.126.79:46650",
"125.26.99.222:57492"]

while True:
    try: #Try: to avoid the code to stop if a proxy don't work or something else don't work 
        s = requests.Session()
        s.headers.update({
        'Host': 'www.xtremetop100.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Referer': 'http://www.xtremetop100.com/in.php?site=1132347673',
        'DNT': '1',
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': '440',
        })
        Proxy = {'http': 'http://' + random.choice(proxy)} # removed https because its useless for your website
        print("proxy = "+str(Proxy)[17:-2]) #[17:2] is to remove the first 17 char and the last 2 to just have the proxy address without https:// etc
        data = {
            'site' :"1132347673",
            'secure_captcha_check':random.randint(1000,9999), #I put a random because it never the same number
            'g-recaptcha-response':"Lol there is a captcha are u serious", #Yeah your vote will be useless now unless there are just using captcha to discourage going further without actually using it 
            'ticki' :"Vote+for+ZeroConquer[New+Server]"
               }
        r = requests.get("http://www.xtremetop100.com/in.php?site=1132347673") #to get cookies
        print(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(r.cookies)) #to show the cooies
        re = s.post(url,data=data, cookies=requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(r.cookies), proxies=Proxy) #GO BOI
        print(r.status_code)
        print(r.reason)
        sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sleep(1) #Sleep to avoid a infinitly spam in the terminal if something goes wrong because its a loop
        pass
```